# Android - Show only head up notification

Tags: java, android, notifications

I just want to show a head up notification that I get from FCM, I do not want to show the notification itself on notification list.

Is that possible?

I do not want to show the notification like this.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.view_achievement_congratulations);
contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.viewAchievementCongrats_image, R.drawable.ic_conquista_desbloqueada);
contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.viewAchievementConquest_tvTitle, PrefsManager.getInstance().getAchievementNotification().getText());

if (PrefsManager.getInstance().getAchievementsCount() == 1) {
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.viewAchievementConquest_tvDescription, Html.fromHtml(PrefsManager.getInstance().getAchievementNotification().getDescription()));
} else {
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.viewAchievementConquest_tvDescription, );
}

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, AchievementsActivity.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_pin_homer)
        .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
        .setContent(contentView)
        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
        .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
```

The head up notification is already showing (which is good) :)

Comment: What do you mean by head up notification. Can you please explain a bit. The head-up notification is not a familiar word to me.

Comment: Reaz Murshed, Here (thats a head up notification): http://www.brevitysoftware.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/android_headup_blog.jpg